# Error when click play video on UIWebview on swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebView` to load the "https://twitter.com/" website. When I successfully loaded and opened the video, when I clicked on the button to enlarge the video, I did not get the desired result, the video displayed full screen, but it was located under `UIWebView` without overlapping. In other cases, the app will crash. someone tell me the cause and how to fix it.
// This is code

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    let url = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/")
    webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = false
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: explain it was located under `UIWebview` without overlapping. And if you are getting a crash then add your crash log to your question

Answer (score 1):

Replace `mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay` line to `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to play video in webview

```
//From    
webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = false
//TO
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```